# Can I have a default npm install and npm install production? (Same as in gulp)

Tags: npm

**Background**
I'm trying to configure a production build for our app. We're using npm/gulp/maven/jenkins. The goal is to install everyting with one command - `mvn install -p production` or `mvn install` for develop (default option).

**Question**
My question is, how do I set a profile in npm to get:
`npm install` - installs stuff from package.json and postinstall `gulp`
`npm install production` - installs stuff from package.json and postinstall `gulp build production`

**Possible solutions**
- npm-config https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config
- npm-scripts - environemnt - https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#environment
- npmrc - https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc
- npm production - https://docs.npmjs.com/all#production
- NODE_ENV or other system variables

There seems to be a way to do it but there are just so many options. How do I choose the right one? (I've read that e.g. NODE_ENV is set differently on different OS). The set up can't be that complicated, can it?

**Final word**
I believe this a valid SO questions since probably someone else sooner or later will bump into the same problem. I will try to find an answer myself but maybe someone has a one-liner that will do it :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why couldn't you have the same (maybe a few extra) dependancies within your `node_modules` folder and then have separate gulp tasks for dev and production. e.g.

`gulp dev` and `gulp dist`

This approach is more the convention having worked with numerous repos and would advise you to go this way instead of trying to complicate something that should be quite simple.

Comment: I have two separate gulp tasks, the thing is I don't want to launch them from gulp but from npm, so that I can make a full installation with one cmd line. `node_modules` and dependencies are irrelevant here.

Comment: So could you not just do `npm install && gulp dist`?

Comment: but then npm install will first install dev and then dist, which I want to avoid.